# Google search console reports rankings, but my site doesn't show up for me when searching for those keywords

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

So I know that positions change and are also tailored to the user personally, but when I am looking at positions in my Webmaster tools dashboard some keywords have positions like 5, 6 or 7 (first page), but when I am actually trying the same keywords in Google search I don't see my website anywhere at all, and I also checked image search.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Search consoles allows you to filter by country, device, and search type.   Have you tried setting the filters to what you are currently using?  For example: United States, Desktop, Web?

Comment: Yes it should appear for web search and it has a similar position in most countries

Comment: Search console is reporting it is appearing in web results for the country you are in, the device type you are using?

Comment: Yes, for a specific keyword it shows position 2.8 in web search for UK where I am also performing the search

Comment: Have you tried searching for those keyword(s) using Chrome Incognito?

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged into your Google account, you can get a user-profile neutral search by clicking this button (borrowed an image from Google):
[image: Hide Private search button]

This private search will give you an idea of where you really rank. Search Console will return where you averagely rank on the user influenced searches. If someone has recently been clicking links to your site - they'll appear higher for that user. Equally, this behaviour with another site will push you further down that you'd be organically. The 'hide private results' is the best way to gauge this.

Comment: I think this is the same as going incognito in Chrome right?

Comment: Incognito removes Google's ability to profile a user - but not IP and Location which will both still tilt results.

Hide Private Results removes these too. It's a weird situation in which identifying yourself actually gets you more neutral results than it would otherwise.